# Jenkins-Parameterized build - Export Parameters+values to text file?

Tags: jenkins, parameterized

***DISCLAIMER*** - I am not a developer :)

I have created a simple Jenkins parameterized job that works perfectly.  However, I want to spit out or export or echo the parameters and their value to a plain text file.  I am unable to find any simple means to do this.

Ironically, Jenkins does echo the exact information I need when I "Build" the job, and it is still pending, in the Build History Column. Then the build completes and the information disappears.  It displays every parameter plus the value exactly in the format I need.  How can I get this information to write to a plain text file?

> EG:  this is how it displays
> Build History
>
> ## 32   (PENDING-???)
>
> ```
>      servername=myservername 
>      domaindir=/domaindirectoryspecified/ 
>      logdir=/logdirectoryspecified/ 
>      username=myuserid 
>      domainname=mynewdomainname
> ```
>
> ## 31   Jan 3,2014 01:05:58 PM
>
> ## 30   Jan 2,2014 11:01:45 AM

Comment: You can do this with a little bit of scripting - are you more familiar with Linux or Windows ?

Comment: Thank you! We only have Windows.

Comment: Windows batch script or NAnt script is the way out.

Answer (score 1):

Add a build step of type "Execute Windows batch command" to your job configuration and write out the parameter values to a file - they will be available as environment variables.  I'm not super familiar with Windows, but something like this should do the trick:

```
@echo off
IF EXIST file goto skip
(echo servername=%servername%) >file 
(echo domaindir=%domaindir%) >>file
... 
:skip
```

(I got the above code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692916/unable-to-echo-user-input-values-to-file-in-batch-script))

Note that the file you create will be relative to the build's workspace directory and will thus be overwritten by the next build.  If you want to keep it somewhere more permanent, use an absolute path e.g. c:\dir\file.

Comment: The script worked, thank you so much!  I was attempting to find a method that would list all the parameters defined, without specifying them individually in the echo statements.  I'm going to use this as a workaround and I deeply appreciate your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin precisely for this matter:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Export+Parameters+Plugin

Alternatively, if you need to export parameters your own way, for example, in case you need to **export a multi-line context from "text parameter"**, you can do it with a [System Groovy Script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin), likewise:

```
envVars = build.getEnvironment()
data_var = "YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME"
data = envVars.get(data_var)
data_file_path = build.workspace.toString() +  "/" +  data_var + ".txt"

if(build.workspace.isRemote())
{
    channel = build.workspace.channel
    fp = new hudson.FilePath(channel, data_file_path)
} else {
    fp = new hudson.FilePath(data_file_path)
}

if(fp != null)
{
    fp.write(data, null)
}
```

Comment: This plugin does not seem to be available in pipeline builds :(