# How to check the result of an overwrite file request in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have searched online for this, but can't seem to find an answer. I have code that creates a text file after asking one what name he/she would like to give the text file. The file is then opened after being created. However, if I choose N (No) to an overwrite request, I don't want the file to open. I would instead want to be asked again to specify another file name after saying N (No) to the overwrite request.

I however have no idea as to how to check the answer given to the overwrite request.

Also, I would need the entire code to be in one line.

This is what I have without the extras that I am mentioned above:

```
cmd /c @ECHO OFF & SET /P filename=What File name: & cmd /v /c copy /-y NUL !filename!.txt & cmd start /v /c start notepad !filename!.txt & Exit
```

**Later Added:**

I am working on the following and keep getting the error message "( was unexpected at this time." after the filename is echoed. If I edit the file by commenting parts out so that it works, and then continue to edit it to what I currently have, it still works. However, if I exit the cmd box, and then start it again, then it doesn't work and I get an error message. This is the code thus far:

```
@echo off
SET /P filename=What File name?
echo %filename%
::loop
if exist !filename!.txt (
echo File Exists
SET /P overwrite=Overwrite File?
echo overwrite is %overwrite%
If %overwrite%==Y (
echo "Yes, Y"
)
)

echo finish
```

If I put single quotes around `%overwrite%` in `If '%overwrite%'==Y` I no longer get the unexpected error message. The problem I still face though is when exiting the session / the cmd box, I can't get the line above to echo the value of overwrite. It just says "overwrite is" (without quotes and with no value after it). If I continue in the same session running the batch file over again, I get a value for overwrite.

**Solution to unable to echo value of `%overwrite%` (user input) from if statement can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692916/unable-to-echo-user-input-values-to-file-in-batch-script).**

Comment: Suggestion: when you get to the point of such complicated CMD files, it's time to switch to PowerShell, which was made for this. CMD wasn't originally designed to do anything this complicated. Such features as multi-line `if` statements are additions (a.k.a., "hacks")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
cmd /v:on /q /c "for /l %a in (0 0 1) do (set /p "file=file? " & if exist "!file!" ( set "q=" & set /p "q=overwrite? " & if /i "!q!"=="y" ( type nul > "!file!" & start "" notepad "!file!" & exit ) ) else ( type nul > "!file!" & start "" notepad "!file!" & exit ))"
```

As requested, in one line. To include it inside a batch file, replace `%a` with `%%a`

**edited** one line, with input validations and error checks added on file operations, and shortened (variables length reduced, unneeded spaces removed, file creation code deduplicated, ...) to fit into windows "Run" dialog

**edited** added initial `cd /d "%userprofile%"` to ensure the working folder is writeable. Why? Because from windows 7, including the `/v:on` (or off) in the call to `cmd` from the windows Run dialog (the OP reason for a one liner), the active directory for the command is  `c:\windows\system32` (or wherever the system is). Without the `/v` switch, the active directory is the user profile folder.

```
cmd /v:on /q /c "cd/d "%userprofile%"&for /l %a in () do ((set/p"f=file? "||set "f=")&(if defined f if exist "!f!" ((set/p"q=overwrite? "||set "q=0")&if /i not "!q!"=="y" (set "f=")))&if defined f (type nul>"!f!" &&(start "" notepad "!f!" &exit)))"
```

**edited** After a lot of tests i make it fail in XP. The previous code will fail if the machine is configured with command extensions disabled. Also, the problem with `Ctrl-C` can be anoying. This should handle the first problem and minimize the second.

```
cmd /v:on /e:on /q /c "cd/d "%userprofile%"&for /l %a in ()do ((set/p"f=file? "||(set f=&cd.))&(if defined f if exist "!f!" ((set/p"q=overwrite? "||(set q=&cd.))&if /i not "!q!"=="y" (set f=)))&if defined f (cd.>"!f!"&&(start "" notepad "!f!" &exit)))"
```

Comment: How can this be modified so that it creates the file and then opens it, so I am not bothered with a prompt telling me the file doesn't exist and asking me if to create it. My multi line solution (well, from examples online and lots of help) does this. In it I have `copy NUL "!filename.txt"` and on the line below it `start "" notepad "!filename!.txt"`. I tried adding `copy NUL "!file! & "` before your final `start`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rolo, answer updated. The code in your comment has some quoting problems that makes it fail.

Comment: Just wondering if there is any safe place to get rid of spaces so that it can be at 259 characters, which seems to be the limit for the Windows run box. I tried experimenting by removing spaces in a few different spots, but it then causes problems. This is 5 characters too long at 264 characters. (Just curious: I don't need to run it this way, plus I learned that I could put the code in a batch file, and then the batch file in the Windows directory and then call in from the Run box.)

Comment: @Rolo, try the added line. More code, less characters. Can be reduced more, but it is harder to read

Comment: Thanks I see that you caught your error of the double %%. I guess maybe it's a security issue on Windows 8, but when I type the code directly in Windows 8's Run box, I get an error message of Access Denied when the file is trying to be created. I don't have this problem on a Win XP computer. On the Windows 8 computer, if I copy the code in the the regular or Administrator command prompt, everything works fine. There's still one issue though, which is the file gets created without any extension. In notepad, I can't simply do Ctrl+S or File > Save, because I am saving to an extension-less file.

Comment: @Rolo, the `%%` was included because i tested it inside a batch file. The script asks for a file. If you do not provide a path for the file the default path is under the windows folder, so, no righs to write to it. The file has no extension if you do not provide it. Include the extension on the file query or modify the script to include one.

Comment: Only mentioned the %% b/c you told me to use it when running the code from a batch file, which I noticed before you corrected it. The default file path if none is specified is not the Windows directory, but rather C:\users\myusername on Win 8. On Win XP, it's the Documents and Settings in place of Users. Anyhow, I am very curious why neither of the codes (for the 1st one I shortened the variable file to f) work on Win 8 when executed from the Run box, yet a code such as this `cmd /q /c type nul > "tYY5.txt" & start "" notepad "tYY5.txt"` works just fine. No problems on Win XP for either code.

Comment: @Rolo, the difference is `/v:on`. Try running `cmd /q /c "echo %cd% & pause"` and `cmd /v:on /q /c "echo %cd% & pause"`. In windows 7, in the second case, the working folder is `c:\windows\system32`, not the user profile folder.

Comment: Oh! O.k. I figured it was most likely that as I tried multiple versions of the code, and though it wasn't working correctly--would create a file named %file% as an extension-less file--the `/v:on` seemed to be what was giving me the access denied. I also remembered, though I didn't pay much attention to it, that you said I can specify the file path. I did so along with a file name, and both codes work. I never knew I could specify the file extension nor the path at the prompt. With the code I have been using, I have `if exists "!filename!.txt"`. Out of curiosity, would one be able

Comment: to specify the folder path along with the SET command? And one more thing. Why doesn't this work?: `cmd /k "set /p "file=file? " & type > nul "%file%" & start "" notepad "%file%""` It creates %file% instead of the file name I specify. If ran from the cmd box twice, on the 2nd run, it creates the file name I specified the first time.

Comment: @Rolo, i've included a `cd/d` in the command to avoid the initial directory change. To include a path in the file, type it when asked, `d:\somewhere\myfile.txt`. As the full command is in one line and one block, when the parser handles it, all variable reads are replaced with the value inside them **before** starting to execute. That is the reason for the delayed expansion. Without it, the changes to the variable values are not visible from inside the same block of code where they were changed

Comment: **WOW! I have learned so much. Thank you.** Regarding the path, I was asking how to include it in the code, but you told me to specify it when asked, which I told you you told me before, however, you indirectly answered this now with the cd/d command, because all I would have to do is then specify the folder path there. For the rest of the explanation, I thought you were just giving me extra info, but then I realized you were answering my question about what's wrong with the sample code I asked about. Including v/:on, changing the % to ! and using cd/d did it. This language is so strange to me

Comment: One final set of comments: 1) I like quick & easy ways to accomplish computer tasks, which is why I find myself looking towards bat files. Should I study more of batch programming or instead PowerShell, VBScript, or something else? 2) Are there editors for batch files? I would like a program to easily put & remove the double colons in front of lines and to check that I have the correct number of quotes. 3) I definitely want to mark this as the answer. If you can please put a note that for 1st code, changing the variable file to something shorter i.e. 1 letter, causes it to fit in the Run box.

Comment: @Rolo, 1) All, and then something else. 2) Notepad++, RJ TextEd, ... any editor with syntax highlight that you can customize to fit your needs. You can not get more. In batch files there is no such thing as *correct number of quotes*/colons/carets. It always depend. 3) It was still in the answer, but i have changed it to what i think is more clear. To mark this as "the" correct answer is always the OP decission.

Comment: Why is it that for either one of these codes the break command (Ctrl + C or Ctrl + Break) does not work? I tested this on both Windows 8 and Windows XP. Either a file of !file! gets created if it doesn't exist or if it does, I am asked if to overwrite. Also, on Windows XP (everything is fine on Windows 8), for the first code, if I shorten the filename so that it can fit in the run box, it works when executed from the run box, but for the 2nd code, the cmd box closes and never asks me for a file name. If I first open up cmd and then paste the 2nd code, then it works. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Rolo, `set /p` + `ctrl-c` have some odd behavior. But in the way you are using the code, you can use Alt-F4. Both codes has been tested both in windows XP and 7 and work as intended (shortening the first code to fit into run box). Without seeing your changed code i can not say way it fails.

Comment: 1) Regarding the behavior of Ctrl + C, I was simply curious and wondered if you knew why it behaved that way with this code. 2) You misunderstood me about the code not working in XP when run from the RUN box. I am not changing anything. I am simply copying and pasting the 2nd code into the Windows XP Run box. Again, just curious. I already have a batch file with multiple lines that I have been using. I am just trying to learn as much as possible from this one example.

Comment: @Rolo, 1) Ctrl+C not always gets correctly handled when there is an input and the following operation is another input. Placing an echo after the input usually mitigates the problem. And no, i have no idea why this behaves that way. 2) I have tested again the code in XP, both run box and cmd window. And for me it works in both.

Comment: @Rolo, answer updated. I have been able to reproduce your problem (or so i think). Test the included code.

Comment: The third code also does not work in Windows XP when run directly from the RUN box. The cmd window opens and immediately closes. The 2nd and 3rd code work if I first open the cmd box and then paste the code. The 1st one works when pasted directly into the RUN box as well as the cmd box. I tried doing a few tests, but couldn't reach any conclusion. When run directly from the RUN box, this works: `cmd /v:on /e:on /q /c "cd/d "%userprofile%" & set/p "f=file?" "` as well as does this: `cmd /v:on /e:on /q /c "cd/d "%userprofile%"&for /l %a in ()do ((set/p"f=file? "))"`

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid overwriting by `copy` in this case (because it's `ERRORLEVEL` ignores overwriting status). You can do everything on your side:

- You can check existance of file (`IF EXISTS !filename!.txt`),
- If file exists, you can ask user what to do (`SET /P userInput=Overwrite? (Yes/No/All)`),
- After it you can analyzed `%userInput%` to decide what to do (delete existent file and create empty one with the same name + open editor or ask file name again).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Unfortunately I do not know how to code in DOS. I have in other languages, but nonetheless, that was a long time ago. The following is what I am working on, but the filename doesn't get set or it remembers a previous filename. Also, I took echo off out so that I can test printing messages: `cmd /c SET /P filename=What File name? & cmd /v /c echo !filename! & IF EXIST !filename!.txt SET /P overwrite=Overwrite File? & IF !overwrite!==N echo No ask new file name ELSE echo unique`

Comment: I recommend you to add flag `/I` after `IF` for case insensitive string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

When using a single line you can't loop back to the start - but this will only create the file AND start notepad with the file, if the file does not exist.

If the file exists it will just exit and NOT start notepad so you know that you have to try again.

```
cmd /c @ECHO OFF & SET /P filename=What File name: & cmd /v /c "if not exist !filename!.txt copy NUL !filename!.txt & start "" notepad !filename!.txt" & Exit
```

Comment: hmm. Well, this does work and since I will be able to easily call up these commands again, I guess I wouldn't mind doing so. No message is displayed to me that the cmd box is exiting because the file already exists, but since this is just for me, I suppose that's fine and that I will remember the code being setup this way. This is interesting. I never thought of looking at it logically from this way of checking if the file does not exist. Question: What are the two quotation marks after start for? Also, so for statements couldn't be used in a single line code? What about multiple if

Comment: statements? Such as (If file exists, prompt user if to overwrite, if answer is yes, overwrite, else if no, ask for new name, then create file and open it) else create file and open it. So this would be a nested (I think this is the correct term) if statement (an if statement within an if statement and would only give the user one chance to come up with a new name. Could that work? If yes, how would I group the if statements--with quotation marks like you did? Thanks.

Comment: If that was implemented it would only prompt once, and if the second filename existed you'd be at the same spot.  The `""` after the start command stops it failing if you ever quote the filename, as the first set of quotes become the `Window Title`.

Comment: You know, you can use a regular batch file and place it on the path, such as `c:\windows` and then just paste in the batch filename into the RUN box.  If you call it `a.bat` then you just have to type `a` into the run box, and you will have looping available to do what you need.

Comment: Yes, I know what I suggested would only work one more time. I did not know one can store a bat file in Windows and that it would work in the RUN box. That's cool Thanks. With the toolbar explorer program I am using, I could also store the bat file anywhere and then tell it where to look. I thought what I wanted to do was simple--create a text file quickly--until I realized I would prefer overwrite protection and a chance to specify another file name in the same session.

Comment: Can you take a look at what I posted above in the original question and let me know what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want another option of also overwriting the file.

Comment: You stated "When using a single line you can't loop back to the start". As @mc-nd demonstrated with his answer, that statement is incorrect.

Comment: @Rolo +1 Using a for loop solves the issue in a clever way, agreed, but it doesn't loop back to the start such as when using a goto and label.  That can't be done in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

`If %overwrite%==Y` : if `%overwrite%` is empty, this is executed as `If ==Y` - obviously a syntax error.

With the singlequoutes you mentioned: `If '%overwrite%'==Y` is executed as `If ''==Y` - this is proper syntax, so your code doesn' fail (but is not running as intended)

The reason why `%overwrite%` is empty: you are using it inside a block (between `if (` and the corresponding `)`, so for parsing reason it' easy (search for `delayed expansion`).
You can easily avoid that:

```
@echo off
SET /P filename=What File name?
echo %filename%
:loop
if not exist %filename%.txt goto finish
echo File Exists
SET /P overwrite=Overwrite File?
echo overwrite is %overwrite%
If "%overwrite%"=="Y" ( echo "Yes, Y" ) else ( goto loop )
this line is never reached    
:finish   
echo finish
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I had already mentioned the solution to the overwrite variable problem and delayed expansion by providing a link in the original question above.