# if [true] and [true] then....else.... batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

People have been great on here so far. Done searching (although invariably not extensively enough!). Why doesn't this work?

```
if [%_dpsUserUpdate%] == [false] if [%_dpsUserPrompt%] == [false] (
    echo Both User Update and Prompt set to false. Run 7z silently.....
    7z e "%_file%" -y > nul
) else (
    echo Either User Update and/or Prompt set to true. Run 7z gui.....
    7zG e "%_file%"
)
```

Aim - if Update and Prompt both set to false, run 7z. Otherwise (for remaining 3 permutations) run 7zG. Works for "false and false" but not for other 3 combinations....

Of course, i could stick a "goto" in there, but that always feels like 'bad' coding (dunno why!).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use if - else structure in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: Try `if [%_dpsUserUpdate%][%_dpsUserPrompt%] == [false][false] (` ...

Comment: You would need to show exactly how you are setting `_dpsuserupdate` and `_dpsuserprompt`.

Comment: And you can force string comparisons to ignore case with **/i** switch: `if /i [%_dpsUserUpdate%][%_dpsUserPrompt%] == [false][false] ( `...

Comment: Thanks Josef. Above produced a break. Command line:
[true] was unexpected at this time.
C:\[blah]>if [false] [true] == [false] [false] (
c:\[blah]>
Magoo - just straight set, i.e.:
set _dpsUserUpdate=true
vars checked - no trailing spaces or such nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not works as intended because the syntax of IF command is this: `if condition command`. This way, you have *two* IF commands and just one ELSE clause, so it is applied to the *last* IF command as usual. In other words, your example is equivalent to this one:

```
if [%_dpsUserUpdate%] == [false] (
    if [%_dpsUserPrompt%] == [false] (
        echo Both User Update and Prompt set to false. Run 7z silently.....
        7z e "%_file%" -y > nul
    ) else (
        echo Either User Update and/or Prompt set to true. Run 7z gui.....
        7zG e "%_file%"
    )
)
```

I think this way is clearer to see:

```
if [%_dpsUserUpdate%] == [false] (
    echo User Update is false
    if [%_dpsUserPrompt%] == [false] (
        echo Both User Update and Prompt set to false.
    ) else (
        echo User Update is false, Prompt is true
    )
) else (
    echo User Update is true
    if [%_dpsUserPrompt%] == [false] (
        echo User Update is true. Prompt is false
    ) else (
        echo User Update is true. Prompt is true
    )
)
```

This is the way I would do it:

```
set "bothAreFalse=true"
if [%_dpsUserUpdate%] neq [false] set "bothAreFalse="
if [%_dpsUserPrompt%] neq [false] set "bothAreFalse="
if defined bothAreFalse (
    echo Both are false
) else (
    echo Anyone of the other three cases
)
```

Comment: I know you're not meant to just say "thanks." But thanks! :) Clarified.

Comment: You may say "thanks" upvoting my answer(s) when you have enough rep to do so... **`;-)`**