# Start a Java application using Bat file if not already started

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, wmic, tasklist

I want to check using a bat file if a Java program is already running. If its not running then start it using `start javaw`.

I have tried `WMIC` and I am only successful so far to get the PID.

```
WMIC process where "CommandLine like '%MyServer.jar%' and Name like '%javaw%'" get ProcessId
```

But how to write an if else condition in the bat file to start?

I tried using tasklist and find

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Programm is running
```

But for all the java applications `myapp.exe` will be `java.exe`.

Please help...

P.S: There are options for this to be done via the Java program itself, but my specific situation asks for a bat file solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jcmd.exe to see the main class of all the java processes running. The IF-ELSE syntax of the batch file is explained in the following thread

[How to use if - else structure in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file)

```
jcmd | find /I /N "sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole"


IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" GTR "0" (
    jconsole.exe
)

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo Programm is running 
)
```

This link would help with the IF construct - http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: Thanks. But what do I do after that. How do I check it in IF. I already get the name using jps -m | find. 
    jps -m | find /i "MYAPP"
6356 MYAPP localhost 1899 C:\TRAMM4.0\TRAMM\ true

Now how do I write the IF else? How can I use a variable? What condition do I check? I am sorry, but I am not that familiar with CMD commands/ scripts of this scale.

Comment: See if the example added above helps. The above program is checking if JConsole is running (main class: sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole) - if its not running it launches it. More information can be found here http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: I feel that jcmd will be easier than jps. The output looks like :
`
$ jcmd
33004 sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd`

Comment: Thanks Akshay. That solved it for me. But when I use that for my application this is what happens,

    C:\FOLDER>TITLE My Server

    C:\FOLDER>jcmd   | find /I /N "MyServer"

    C:\FOLDER>IF "1" GTR "0" (
    cd bin
     set filename= C:FOLDER\
start javaw -classpath ../lib/*;MyServer.jar .cig.MyAPP.Myserver.MyServer localhost 1899 C:FOLDER\ true
)

C:\FOLDER\bin>IF 0 EQU 0 (echo Programm is running  )
Programm is running

C:\FOLDER\bin>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

As you see the whole thing is being printed on the console. How can I avoid that and print only 'Program Is Running'?

Comment: You need to turn echo off "@echo off"