# Bash script to start java if not running, with other java programs running

Tags: java, bash

i usually use this bash script to check if my java application is running and start it again if not. I use crontab to check it

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(pidof java)" ]
then
  # process was found
        echo "application running"
else
  # process not found
cd /home/assist/emanager
setsid java -jar emanager-1.0.0.jar </dev/zero &>/dev/null &
fi
```

Now the problem is that there are other java applications running on the server, so the script does not start my app because the if condition is true. Is there a way to check if a specific java application is running?

Thanks

Comment: grep for `emanager-1.0.0.jar` in the process list?

Comment: Writing a PID file when emanager application start, unlink it at exit. This may be done by the launcher script or by the application itself.

Comment: You could also create a 'lock' file when the application starts and delete it when it exits, then check if the 'lock' file exists.

Comment: so, I should use a script to automatically start the application at startup, write the pid on a file or create a lock file, and check if it exists...

Comment: what would be the workflow if you add the restart kind of script  to restart the jar once again even if its already running ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to this one:
[Start a Java application using Bat file if not already started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348758/start-a-java-application-using-bat-file-if-not-already-started)

The main difference is you are asking for bash while the other one is in Windows. Hence replace jcmd with jps, the rest is still applicable.