# How do I get the result of the query to a variable (from sqlcmd to batch/cmd)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

I've got most of what I want below, I just need to know how to;

1. Collect the variable from the sql result
2. Take the next action based on the results of the collected variable

What I need to happen is put in a;

If the `updatedDate` is before 3 days ago, then `GOTO BREXIT` (ignore time). I'd prefer to handle this outside of the *.sql as I'd like to use this in other applications.

e.g.1

- updatedDate = 5/12/2016 14:30
- 3 days ago = 2/12/2016 00:00
- RESULT = GOTO EXTRACT

e.g.2

- updatedDate = 6/12/2016 02:30
- 3 days ago = 2/12/2016 00:00
- RESULT = GOTO BREXIT

The code is currently as follows (Comments are not coded yet):

```
echo Check last update 
sqlcmd -S MYSERVER\JD2016 -d OMNITRIX -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT MAX(updateDateTime) 'updatedDate' FROM dbo.Names;" -h-1 -b

::(if statement would go here)

:EXTRACT
echo Running Omnitrix Extract
sqlcmd -S MYSERVER\JD2016 -d OMNITRIX -i "C:\update.sql" -W -s; -h-1 > "C:\result.csv" -b

echo Omnitrix has been extracted

GOTO END

::(:BREXIT)
::(echo Please Update the Omnitrix)

:END
pause
```

Comment: See this link regarding IF ELSE in a batch file:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Thanks for your response! I know how to handle flow - my question was more or less, how to capture the result of the query (i.e. 05/12/2016 15:13) into x, read only the date (05/12/2016) and then compare that date to the Current Date - 3

Comment: If you have the solution you could post it as an answer here and even accept it...

Comment: I don't actually have the solution though... I don't know how to get 05/12/2016 to x and then use that

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I suggest you to check your max date expiration directly in first sql. I.e.:

```
select case 
  when datediff(getdate(), max(yourdate)) > 3 then 'needupdate' 
  else 'ok' end 
from ...
```

and then look at [Windows batch assign output of a program to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable)

May be commenting with link would be enough, but suggestion too long...)