# how to use something like if and else in batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

```
@echo off
mode 1000
goto block1


:block1
echo color
goto block2


:block2
pause
set /a num=%random% %%5
goto 0

:0
if num == 0 goto a
goto 1


:1
if num == 1 goto b
goto 2


:2
if num == 2 goto c
goto 3


:3
if num == 3 goto d
goto 4


:4
if num == 4 goto e
goto 5


:5 
if num == 5 goto f
goto 0

:a
color 0a
goto block2


:b
color 0b
goto block2


:c
color 0c
goto block2


:d
color 0d
goto block2


:e
color 0e
goto block2


:f
color 0f
goto block2
```

i want to make a color sign witch changes colors and i would like use simething like this . but i cant use else in batch and it would need something like that

Comment: What exactly are you asking, and what's not working with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use if - else structure in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: In batch files the syntax to refer to a variable name (`num`) differs from the syntax to obtain the variable content (`%num%`)

Answer (score 0):

- From batch view point nearly all the `goto`s are useless and only
  result in spaghetti code.
- You are aware that a color stement will affect the whole screen?
- `%random%` modulus 5 can only return `0..4`

Your code shortened :

```
@echo off
mode 1000
echo color
:block2
pause
set /a num=%random% %%5
if %num% == 0 color 0a
if %num% == 1 color 0b
if %num% == 2 color 0c
if %num% == 3 color 0d
if %num% == 4 color 0e
goto block2
```

Comment: Simpler: initialize `set "color=abcde"` and then use `color !color:~%num%,1!` instead of all those `if`'s (with Delayed Expansion Enabled).

Comment: That was my first thought too, but wanted to stay with the simple code of OP @Aacini