# How can I add multiple if else conditions for choice parameter?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following value for the choice parameter:

Name: Param
Choices:

- Test1
- Test2
- Test3

And an Execute windows batch command :

```
if (%Param% == "Test1") (
echo "1"
) else if (%Param% == "Test2") (
echo "2"
) else (
echo "3"
) ---is not working

if (%Param% == "Test1") (
echo "1"
) else ( if (%Param% == "Test2") (
echo "2") else (
echo "3"
)
) ---is not working
```

Comment: How is this related to jenkins?

Comment: Batch doesn't really support else like this.  See this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file

Comment: You need to change your comparisons, because the doublequotes are included. Change it to either this format `If "%Param%"=="Test1"`, _(preferred)_, or `If %Param%==Test1`. You should probably choose to use `If`'s `/I` option too, to make the comparison case insensitive.

Comment: As your example looks quite construed, your use case isn't clear to me. Do you want to validate a user input via `set /P` or passed as cmd line argument?

Answer (score 1):

```
set "Param=Test2"

if "%Param%" == "Test1" (
    echo "1"
) else if "%Param%" == "Test2" (
    echo "2"
) else (
    echo "3"
)
```

Almost had it in the 1st example.
You do not enclose the comparison to test between `(` and `)` in batch-file.

Comparisons are literal, so what is on one side needs to match the other side.
This includes the double quotes. So, variables without quotes may require them
to match e.g. `"%Param%" == "Test1"`. `%Param% == "Test1"` would never match
in the example above as the value of `%Param%` has no double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop **`For /L`**?

```
For /l %%i In (1 1 3) Do If "%Param%"=="Test%%~i" Echo="%%i"
```